# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(l-a_k)$ converges if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1\cdot a_2\cdot ...\cdot a_n}{l^n}=C$ for some $C>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a nondecreasing sequence of positive numbers converging to some limit $l$.
Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(l-a_k)$ converges if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1\cdot a_2\cdot ...\cdot a_n}{l^n}=C$ for some $C>0$.

My thoughts:

In the "forward" direction, Given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that whenever $m > n\geq N$,
$|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}(1-\frac{a_k}{l})| < \frac{\varepsilon}{l}$ by the Cauchy Criterion.

We also know that $\lim\frac{a_n}{l}=1$ with $0<\frac{a_n}{l}<1$ for all $n$.

For finite $N$ we know that $(a_1a_2...a_N)/l^N$ is also positive and finite.

If anyone could offer any hints that'd be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $l\geq a_1>0$. Let $b_k=1-\frac {a_k} l$. The statement now becomes  the following:

$\sum b_k$ converges if and only if $\prod (1-b_k)$ converges to a positive number. This equivalence is a standard fact about infinite products. It is proved by going to logarithms and using that fact that $\ln (1+x) \sim x$ as $x \to 0$.  Ref: Rudin's RCA.

Comment: If $a_k$ is a non-decreasing sequence of positive numbers, then $l=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}a_k\ge a_1\gt0$.

Comment: @robjohn You are right. Thank you.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sorry accidentally hit enter when I wanted to create a new line. 
I was also wondering how you would articulate that ln(1 + x) ~ x in a "epsilon-delta" proof. 
For example, Given epsilon > 0, there exists an N such that whenever n > m >= N, |b_{m+1} + b_{m+2} + ... + b_{n} | < epsilon and |b_{n}| < epsilon. 
I was hoping that this could lead to |ln(1-b_{m+1}) + ln(1-b_{m+2}) + ... + ln(1-b{n})| < epsilon. But I don't know error for ln(1 + x) ~ x, which I believe would be the first step toward making a claim like that.

Comment: @person  A precise argument (of a more general result) is available in Rudin's book. You can look for 'infinite prodiucts' in the index.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is along similar lines as that of geetha290km, but here is a non-logarithmic proof that the sum and related product converge together.

---

Let $b_k=1-\frac{a_k}{l}$, then the question becomes

> Let $(b_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a non-increasing sequence of numbers in $[0,1)$ converging to $0$.
>
> Show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ converges if and only if $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty(1-b_k)\gt0$.

**Theorem:** Suppose that $0\le b_k\lt1$, then
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{1\mp b_k}\ge\prod_{k=1}^n(1\pm b_k)\ge1\pm\sum_{k=1}^nb_k\tag1
$$
**Proof:** The left-hand inequality of $(1)$ follows simply from $(1-x)(1+x)=1-x^2\le1$. We will show the right-hand inequality of $(1)$ by induction.

$(1)$ is trivial for $n=1$. Assume we have $(1)$ for $n-1$:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1\pm b_k)\ge1\pm\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k\tag2
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^n(1\pm b_k)
&=(1\pm b_n)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1\pm b_k)\tag{3a}\\
&\ge(1\pm b_n)\left(1\pm \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k\right)\tag{3b}\\
&=1\pm\sum_{k=1}^nb_k+b_n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}b_k\tag{3c}\\
&\ge1\pm\sum_{k=1}^nb_k\tag{3d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a):}$ pull the $k=n$ term out front
$\text{(3b):}$ apply $(2)$
$\text{(3c):}$ expand the product
$\text{(3d):}$ $b_k\ge0$

Thus, we have $(1)$ for $n$.

$\large\square$

Convergence is dependent on what happens in the tail of the sequence of partial sums/products. Thus, if the sum converges, by removing a finite number of terms, we can assume that the partial sum is less than $\frac12$. Furthermore, if the product converges, by removing a finite number of terms, we can assume that the partial product of $1-b_k$ is between $\frac12$ and $1$ (and that the partial product of $1+b_k$ is between $1$ and $2$).

The Theorem says
$$
1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\le\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-b_k)\tag4
$$
which says that if the sum converges, the product is bounded below, so it converges to a positive value.

Furthermore,
$$
1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k\le\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1-b_k)\right)^{-1}\tag5
$$
which says that if the product converges to a positive value, the sum is bounded above and so it converges.

Comment: From (4) we conclude that if the sum converges then the product is bounded below by a positive number and must be positive, but how do we know that $1 - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k$ isn't negative?

Comment: This is where the passage "Thus, if the sum converges, by removing a finite number of terms, we can assume that the partial sum is less than $\frac12$" comes into play. We can remove that finite product and see that the product of the terms whose sum is less than $\frac12$ gives a non-vanishing product. Then we can replace the finite product that we removed.

Comment: The statement at the beginning is not entirely precise. Take $b_1 =2$ and $b_n=n^{-2}$ for $n\geq 2$. The product is negative but the series still converge.

Comment: @Gary: I have restricted the statement to match the question.