# Show without a computer that : $\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\pi-\ln(3+\gamma)<0$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant

Tags: inequality, logarithms, power-series, pi, euler-mascheroni-constant

Challenging problem :

Show that :

$$\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\pi-\ln(3+\gamma)<0$$

I come up with this inequality with [What is the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x!x!!!x!!!!!...}{x!!x!!!!x!!!!!!...}\right)^{-\frac{1}{x}}=^?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527236/what-is-the-limit-lim-x-to-0-left-fracxxx-xxx)

I can show the inequalities :

$$\frac{\pi}{2}-1<\gamma<\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Using the Leibniz formula (expansion of arctangent) and the first harmonic number using a computer .
It doesn't help here

We can also use continued fraction for $\pi$ and for $\gamma$ see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstantContinuedFraction.html

We can also continue to get :

$$\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\pi-\ln\left(3+\gamma\right)+\sqrt{2}\ln\left(1+\left(1+\gamma-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+\left(1+\gamma-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{3}\right)>0$$

How to show it by hand without a computer ?

Comment: We have also $$\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\pi-\ln\left(3+\gamma\right)+\sqrt{2}\ln\left(1+\left(1+\gamma-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+\left(1+\gamma-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{3}\right)-\frac{1}{3}\ln\left(1+\left(1+\gamma-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{4}\right)-6\ln\left(1+\left(1+\gamma-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{5}\right)-70\ln\left(1+\left(1+\gamma-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{6}\right)\simeq 0$$

Comment: This is a hard one. It is fairly easy to establish
$$3<\pi<\frac{22}{7}$$
And
$$\frac{39}{72}<\gamma<\frac{49}{72}$$
Without using any software, but I don't think these bounds are tight enough.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks for the reply . What about continued fraction ?

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: @K.defaoite See the bountied answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4330847/showing-sqrt-frace2-cdot-frace-pi-left-frace2-frac1e-right